# Guidelines to writers worth exploring

Tags: discussion

I saw [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25489/quel-auteur-parmi-ceux-nomm%c3%a9s-ci-dessous-devrais-je-lire-d-abord) concerning worthy French writers has been put on hold, though I believed it could be useful and generate a few good recognized authors most people would agree on.

Since reading novels is also an excellent way to sink into a new language and learn vocabulary, grammar, and tricks on how to express more complex thoughts, I still believed it might be a good addition to the French SE. After all, [a long list](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics) of common false beliefs in mathematics stayed alive and well on Math Overflow.

Would a community wiki following the same line have been a better choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an overall SE policy to discourage primarily opinion-based questions for which no "good answer" could be given.

We could set up a community wiki on Meta ([see on ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english)), but I hardly think you can compare a list of writers to a list of resources or a list of false beliefs. But still it could be worth trying...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I'll sure try to find a way to word and present your proposal in such a way that it stands a chance to bloom and become helpful.